# How was this encoded?

Tags: encoding, decoding

how was this encoded text was encoded and how to decode it :
first one :
ypyRnGbk9F2FpFpvg82oZg==

second :
J9ogXUFPvXPSgj+VSSEVOA==

third:
8Qm87EDRIB9J0imjma5g3JwUP6zRfdQgaecIJlc5RGePzGKIX0Nt4PKikixX0VYL

fourth :
OaSwAcMhjclCMPlRbbZ00A==

fifth :
pnt2lBNgWugh7LBMGbJArQ==

note : im just trying to make it easier if you could recognize any of those ,
i tried base 64 but didn't work
anyone have any idea

Comment: @andrew, well, when trying to manually decode encrypted "known" view state strings, what else could the purpose be but screen-scraping, hacking, reverse engineering etc?

Comment: how did you know it was "known"?

Answer (score 2):

it looks like base64 to me - the padding (trailing =) is consistent with that.

and what do you mean by "didn't work"?  at least the first three decode fine for me (although i get binary data, not, say, ASCII).

to decode in python:

```
from base66 import b64decode
print b64decode('ypyRnGbk9F2FpFpvg82oZg==')
```

which will give you a "mess" because it's binary data.  that particular string might be utf16:

```
print b64decode('ypyRnGbk9F2FpFpvg82oZg==').decode('utf16')
```

which gives something with chinese(?) characters, but others are not.

you need to understand that the basic kind of data in computer is a byte (a number between 0 and 255).  that is what you are getting from b64decode.  ASCII is a way of using those numbers to represent western characters, and if this was ASCII then you'd see the text when python prints out the result.  UTF8 and UTF16 are more complicated ways of storing text in digits that you need to "decode" as above.

just to be clear, the binary data is the output from `b64decode`, so you might store it in a variable:

```
my_binary_data = b64decode('ypyRnGbk9F2FpFpvg82oZg==')
```

Comment: sure, but that just means that it's not text - it's binary data (it's not ASCII, UTF-8 or UTF-16, at least).

Comment: could you give me the decoding results please ?

Comment: oh, is the binary data being decoded also ?, sorry im noob in these stuff

Comment: normally you use base64 for binary data (if you have text, you can just send text).  it might be compressed text, although it's a bit short for that.

Comment: could i have the binary data of any of those results you got and how to decode it to a normal text ?

Comment: I'm sorry but im still unable to understand this, you mean.. decode ypyRnGbk9F2FpFpvg82oZg== from base64 to normal text then it will give me binary data ( Êœ‘œfäô]…¤ZoƒÍ¨f ) then what ?

Comment: that depends on where the data came from.  numbers can mean anything on a computer.  there's nothing in the data that says what it "is" - that has to come from outside.

Comment: i decoded one of them and got ñ ¼ì@Ñ IÒ)£�®`Ü�?¬Ñ}Ô iç&W9Dg�Ìb�_Cmàò¢�,WÑV it's actually as you said but i still don't get it how to decode this ?, could you decode it to a normal text, i would compare them and know what did you exactly do

Comment: that is what i got too.  that is all there is.  that is what python displays when it is binary data.  python doesn't "know" whether numbers are numbers or text, it just does the best it can.  really, you need to start learning about computers and programming with an introductory text book - i can't explain how a computer works here.

Comment: so they are unable to be decoded to a regular text ?

Comment: the data you gave will *always* decode to the same binary data that you have.  that is what base64 gives you.  now perhaps there is some way to then decode that binary data to get text.  but i don't know how and you clearly don't.

Comment: ypyRnGbk9F2FpFpvg82oZg==   this one is should be " male " , will it help ?

Comment: and this should be " female " rbb7+hYSyhflaoAEJ/PjqQ==

Comment: oh!  so you know what they should be?  why didn't you say earlier?  still, i don't know, how can get from the binary data to those texts, sorry.

Comment: no, i just knew one and that's it but it's ok ty anyways :)